# validation fails when I tried to test using Postman with an image file

Tags: laravel, postman

I can't see if my code is working because validation fails when I try with postman. What I did with the postman is below.

what I did with Postman

```
unchecked header.
in the body, form-data
key: profile_photo
type:file
value: test.png (which is in the public folder of laravel)
```

rules

```
 protected $create_rules = [

        'username'  =>  'required|max:20|unique:users,username',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required',
        // **in Production **
        // 'password' => [
        //     'required',
        //     'min:6',
        //     'regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/',
        //     'confirmed'
        // ],
        /**
         * Three of the five rules. 
         * English uppercase characters (A – Z)
         * English lowercase characters (a – z)
         * Base 10 digits (0 – 9)
         * Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
         * Unicode characters
         */

        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:5',
        'role' => 'required',
        'profile_photo.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg'


    ];
```

Comment: did you check $request->all()? does request contain everything you need?

Comment: Are you only going to be uploading one photo at a time? Can you also show the exact error you're getting?